# Cannot update Stock Item Quantity for a Product in Magento 1.6.2

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I am trying to update the stock quantities of products in Magento from within a script.

I load the product, set the stock quantity, and save - but the quantity remains unchanged.

```
// get stock data
$stockData = $product->getStockItem();
printf(PHP_EOL.'Stock: qty=%d, instock=%s, man_stock=%s, use_cfg_man_stock=%s'.PHP_EOL,
    $stockData->getData('qty'),
    $stockData->getData('is_in_stock'),
    $stockData->getData('manage_stock'),
    $stockData->getData('use_config_manage_stock')
);
// prints out qty=0, instock=, man_stock=, use_cfg_man_stock=


// $stockQty = 1
$product->stockItem->setData('qty', $stockQty);
$product->stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', $stockQty>0 ? 1 : 0);
$product->stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
$product->stockItem->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0);

$product->save();                           
$product->load();                           
$stockData = $product->getStockItem();
printf('New Stock: qty=%d, instock=%s, man_stock=%s, use_cfg_man_stock=%s'.PHP_EOL,
    $stockData->getData('qty'),
    $stockData->getData('is_in_stock'),
    $stockData->getData('manage_stock'),
    $stockData->getData('use_config_manage_stock')
);
// prints out qty=0, instock=, man_stock=, use_cfg_man_stock=
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I actually got an `Integrity constraint violation` when attempting to save the stock item or product, but @nachito solution resolved it for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All you were missing is to save the `$stockItem`. You shouldn't need to create a new `stock_item` nor should you have to save the product.

```
if (!($stockItem = $product->getStockItem())) {
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
    $stockItem->assignProduct($product)
              ->setData('stock_id', 1)
              ->setData('store_id', 1);
}
$stockItem->setData('qty', $stockQty)
          ->setData('is_in_stock', $stockQty > 0 ? 1 : 0)
          ->setData('manage_stock', 1)
          ->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0)
          ->save();
```

Comment: Do you need to `setData('stock_id', 1)` twice?

Comment: Second `setData()` is *store_id*

Comment: Works in Magento 1.9 properly

Comment: Works fine on CE 1.7.0.2 in module setup script. I've lost hours before finding the right (your) answer!

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it myself:

```
// get stock data
$stockData = $product->getStockItem();
printf(PHP_EOL.'Stock: qty=%d, instock=%s, man_stock=%s, use_cfg_man_stock=%s'.PHP_EOL,
    $stockData->getData('qty'),
    $stockData->getData('is_in_stock'),
    $stockData->getData('manage_stock'),
    $stockData->getData('use_config_manage_stock')
);
// prints out qty=0, instock=, man_stock=, use_cfg_man_stock=


// $stockQty = 1
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
$stockItem->assignProduct($product);
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
$stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1);
$stockItem->setData('store_id', 1);
$stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 0);
$stockItem->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0);
$stockItem->setData('min_sale_qty', 0);
$stockItem->setData('use_config_min_sale_qty', 0);
$stockItem->setData('max_sale_qty', 1000);
$stockItem->setData('use_config_max_sale_qty', 0);
$stockItem->setData('qty', $stockQty);
$stockItem->save();

$product->save();                           
$product->load();                           
$stockData = $product->getStockItem();
printf('New Stock: qty=%d, instock=%s, man_stock=%s, use_cfg_man_stock=%s'.PHP_EOL,
    $stockData->getData('qty'),
    $stockData->getData('is_in_stock'),
    $stockData->getData('manage_stock'),
    $stockData->getData('use_config_manage_stock')
);
// prints out qty=1, instock=1, man_stock=0, use_cfg_man_stock=0
```

By creating a new StockItem, and assigning that to the product. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

To display stock quantity for the product -

```
 <?php echo $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product); ?>
```

And if you want to display individual data use this -

```
<?php echo $stock->getQty(); ?> // Will display stock quantity
<?php echo $stock->getMinQty(); ?> // Will display minimum quantity
<?php echo $stock->getMinSaleQty(); ?> //will display minimum salable quantity
```

Comment: nice snippet `Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);` I used to use `$prodotto->getStockItem()` but when `$prodotto` is load by `loadByAttribute()` it is a `Varien_Object` and not `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got the same problem with products that I've imported programmatically.
I just realized that I forgot to add *stock_data* in the array...

```
'name' => $productName,
'stock_data' => array(
                        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                        'manage_stock' => 0,
                        'qty' => 0,
                        'stock_id' => 1,
                        'min_qty' => 0,
                    )
```

Without stock data information, Magento generates an exception(at \Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item) when adding product to cart.

With this node, it works. =)