# Access stock qty

Tags: magento, collections, stock

The code below gets the product id at the store

```
$products = $this->getRequest()->getParam('super_group');
```

then I would like to get this product stock qty to add in a condition and choose between two phrases and show it in an ajax pop up.

The first frase is: product added correctly to your shipping cart, and the second one is: the stock qty is lower than you want to buy.

I already tried to use magento collection but it doen't work.

If it's necessary i can add more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$product->getStockItem();
```

You can find additionnal information about updating at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11140724/2660794