# Not able to change stock quanitity

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to adjust the stock of a product with Mage. But for some reason all my changes are ignored and I don't get an errormessage at all.

I already did a lot of research on google and ended with this code snipped if found here ([Cannot update Stock Item Quantity for a Product in Magento 1.6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139516/cannot-update-stock-item-quantity-for-a-product-in-magento-1-6-2)).

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', "test_7");



               $stockData = $product->getStockItem();
               printf(PHP_EOL.'Stock: qty=%d, instock=%s, man_stock=%s, use_cfg_man_stock=%s'.PHP_EOL,
               $stockData->getData('qty'),
               $stockData->getData('is_in_stock'),
               $stockData->getData('manage_stock'),
               $stockData->getData('use_config_manage_stock')
               );
               // prints out qty=0, instock=, man_stock=, use_cfg_man_stock=


               // $stockQty = 1
               $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
               $stockItem->assignProduct($product);
               $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
               $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1);
               $stockItem->setData('store_id', 1);
               $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 0);
               $stockItem->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0);
               $stockItem->setData('min_sale_qty', 0);
               $stockItem->setData('use_config_min_sale_qty', 0);
               $stockItem->setData('max_sale_qty', 1000);
               $stockItem->setData('use_config_max_sale_qty', 0);
               $stockItem->setData('qty', $stockQty);
               $stockItem->save();

               $product->save();
               $product->load();
               $stockData = $product->getStockItem();
               printf('New Stock: qty=%d, instock=%s, man_stock=%s, use_cfg_man_stock=%s'.PHP_EOL,
               $stockData->getData('qty'),
               $stockData->getData('is_in_stock'),
               $stockData->getData('manage_stock'),
               $stockData->getData('use_config_manage_stock')
               );
```

But for some reason, the response is still:

> Stock: qty=0, instock=, man_stock=, use_cfg_man_stock= New Stock:
>   qty=0, instock=1, man_stock=0, use_cfg_man_stock=0

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you reindexed the Stock Status index after applying the changes?

Comment: No, is this necessary (because it was never mentioned in any of the tutorials)? Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary in most setups... Look at my answer for the code to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I use something along the lines of the following in a CLI script. Please make sure to reindex after applying the following code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', "test_7");

if($product) {
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
    if(!$stockItem->getId()) {
        $stockItem->setData('product_id', $product->getId());
        $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1);
    }

    $stockItem->setData('qty', 1);
    $stockItem->setData('min_qty', 1);
    $stockItem->setData('use_config_min_qty', 0);
    $stockItem->setData('is_qty_decimal', 0);
    /** Add other stockinformation from list below **/

    $stockItem->save();
} else {
    // product not found
}
```

Make sure when using this code in a loop that `$stockItem` and `$product` are garbaged after the save.

In the code where I mention other stockinformation fields, use the following:

- qty
- min_qty
- use_config_min_qty
- is_qty_decimal
- backorders
- use_config_backorders
- min_sale_qty
- use_config_min_sale_qty
- max_sale_qty
- use_config_max_sale_qty
- is_in_stock
- use_config_notify_stock_qty
- manage_stock
- use_config_manage_stock
- stock_status_changed_automatically
- type_id

Extra bonus; reindexing programmatically:

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('cataloginventory_stock');
$process->reindexAll();
```

It might even be better to reindex all indices:

```
$indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
    $index->reindexAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this code a go for setting stock values;

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
$stockItem->assignProduct($product);
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
$stockItem->setData('qty', $stockQty);
$product->setStockItem($stockItem);
```