# Magento product stocks import

Tags: magento

I've got a module which fetches products and stock info in one batch from an external API. 
The product import works fine, but the stock doesn't.
Stocks get updated only if I run the import again.

Basically here's how:

```
$product = $this->getCatalogProduct()->loadByAttribute('sku', $code);
if (!$product) {
    $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
}    

$product->set****();
// etc
$product->save();

$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
if (!$stockItem->getId()) {
    $stockItem->setData('product_id', $product->getId());
    $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1);
}
$stockItem->setData('qty', (int) $qty);
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', $qty ? 1 : 0);
$stockItem->save();
```

So the stock qty gets updated only if I run the stock update code twice, not on the same go when the product also gets created.

Comment: The solution to this problem was found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139516/cannot-update-stock-item-quantity-for-a-product-in-magento-1-6-2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import the Stock From API then use this magento extension

this can import the data from API via XML

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/auto-product-import-with-xml-and-webservice-17704.html

If this is not useful then let me know we can import via direct magento sql

which can take less time and solve your Problem

Comment: It's not a simple product import from xml. It uses cron schedules to synchronize data between 2 applications, so using an extension is not a solution.

Comment: yeah i am very sure this extension fulfill your requirement "cron schedules to synchronize data between 2 applications" visit the url and let me know

Comment: I've visited it an checked out the demo. It is not what I need.